# Prove that no new numbers are generated after 1 iterations no matter how big $N$ is.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, fractions, computational-mathematics

Given a positive integer N,

1. Define limit $L= \lfloor N^{1/2} \rfloor$
2. Create a list of number    $\lfloor N/i \rfloor $ for all $i \in [1,\lceil N^{1/2} \rceil +1]$   but $\ge L$.
3. On second iteration choose the next largest number in
   the list ie $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor $ as numerator and repeat above step(ie only step2, not step 1) for all i such that new generated numbers are $\ge L$ and add the newly generated numbers to the list.On third iteration with next biggest currently in list(ie till second   iteration) ie
   $\lfloor N/3 \rfloor $ and so on.

```
    def generate_new_elems(N, L):
        # print("doing for", N)
        N_sq = int(N ** 0.5)
        touch_points = []
        for i in range(2, N_sq + 2):
            if N // i < L:
                break
            else:
                touch_points.append(N // i)
        return [N] + touch_points
    
    highest_iteration = 0
    for StartingN in range(2, 10000):
        L = int(StartingN ** 0.5)
        touch_points = generate_new_elems(StartingN, L)
        iteration_cnt = 1
    
        for i in range(1, len(touch_points)):
            new_elems = generate_new_elems(touch_points[i], L)
            old_size = len(touch_points)
            for e in new_elems:
                if e not in touch_points:
                    touch_points.append(e)
            touch_points.sort()
            touch_points.reverse()
            print(touch_points)
            print(iteration_cnt)
            new_size = len(touch_points)
            if old_size != new_size:
                iteration_cnt = i+1
    
        highest_iteration = max(highest_iteration, iteration_cnt)
        print(StartingN, iteration_cnt)
        print("highest_iteration=", highest_iteration)
```

We find, beyond 1st iteration no new numbers are being generated.

**Prove that it takes no more than 1 iterations to reach a stable point ie a stage such that no new number outside the list is generated for further iterations.**

I have run programatic simulation all $N$s till 10 million and found in no case it takes more than 1 iterations to reach stable state.

**Example:**

- $N=100$,

After 1st iteration: $[100, 50, 33, 25, 20, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10]$

So for $N=100$, only one iteration is needed to reach stable state.

For $N=100$ case it remains same no matter how many times you iterate.

Comment: Are you getting a completely new list with each iteration or adding on to the previous list? Maybe an example would help...

Comment: A concrete example might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the example. With $N=100$ the first list would be $(100, 50, 33, 25, 20, 16, 14, \ldots, 4, 3, 2, 1)$. What happens next?

Comment: Why are small numbers not appearing in your list? e.g. 1 = floor(N/N) should appear in each list.

Comment: If you have some code to perform this algorithm maybe that would help explain what you mean.

Comment: I see - in that case the usual notation would be to use ellipses (...) to indicate the continuing pattern as in Martin's comment above. Without ellipses, we assume you gave the entire list.

Comment: For $N= 2352$, since $ L= \sqrt{N} \approx 48.5$, why is $ 48  < L$ added in the 7th step?  I suspect there's an error in your code that introduced this value, or maybe you're thinking of a different algorithm than what you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important fact for this problem is that $\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{N}{ab}\rfloor$. Proof:

Let $q,r\in\Bbb{N}\space |\space\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor=qb+r,0\le r\lt b$

So $q$ is the quotient of $\frac{\lfloor\frac{N} {a}\rfloor}{b}$ and $r$ is the remainder of $\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}$.

This implies:$$\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}=q+\frac{r}{b}\quad [1]$$ and $$\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\rfloor=q\quad [2]$$
Clearly,
$$\frac{N}{a}-\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor\lt 1 \quad[3]$$
$$\frac{N}{ab}-\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\lt \frac{1}{b} \quad[4]$$
$$\frac{N}{ab}\lt\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}+ \frac{1}{b} \quad[5]$$

Using eq. [1] we can substitute $\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}$ for $q+\frac{r}{b}$

$$\frac{N}{ab}\lt q+\frac{r}{b}+ \frac{1}{b} \quad[6]$$

To maximize $\frac{N}{ab}$ we let $r$ be the maximum value $b-1$.

$$\frac{N}{ab}\lt q+\frac{b-1}{b}+ \frac{1}{b} \quad[7]$$

$$\frac{N}{ab}\lt q+\frac{b-1+1}{b} \quad[8]$$

$$\frac{N}{ab}\lt q+\frac{b}{b} \quad[9]$$

Clearly,

$$\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor\le\frac{N}{a}\quad[10]$$

$$\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\le\frac{N}{ab}\quad[11]
$$

Now using [1],[11], and [9] we have the following inequality:

$$q\le\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\le\frac{N}{ab}\lt q+1 \quad[12]$$

$$q=\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{N}{ab}\rfloor\quad[13]$$

**QED**

This means that iterations after the first are redundant. For example the third term in the second iteration is $\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\rfloor}{3}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{N}{6}\rfloor$ This is the same term as the sixth term for the first iteration.

All elements of iterations beyond the first will just create elements that was already created by the first. So in general
The $b^{th}$ element of the $a^{th}$ iteration will be the $(a*b)^{th}$ element of the first iteration.

Comment: yes with the fix in code you suggested, the question turns out to be wrong but changing 7 to 1 makes the question still valid. Instead of closing the question I changed it to 1. apologies for the pain.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini I have updated my answer to address the current question

Comment: Well I am not convinced. 50/6 = 8.33 but for successive iterations we are not starting with 16.67 but we are starting with 16, so 16/2 = 8. It holds because $\lfloor 8.33 \rfloor == 8$, but the proof should cover why for all cases such taking floor holds.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini I edited my answer I think it will be much more convincing.

Comment: how are you writing $\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\le\frac{N}{ab}$ on [10] ?

Comment: I get $q \le \frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\lt q+1$ from [1] and $\frac{N}{ab} \lt q+1 $ from [9]. But can I say combining [1]&[9] we get [10] ?

Comment: we don't have any inequality above where $something \le \frac{N}{ab} $

Comment: @sibillalazzerini you are correct that I don't explicitly show that $\frac{\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor}{b}\le\frac{N}{ab}
$ from any of my numbered statements, however, it is very easy to show this is the case. Clearly $\lfloor\frac{N}{a}\rfloor\le\frac{N}{a}$ then I just divide both sides by $b$.

Comment: cool looks good. I can accept it now. please add that as well as a numbered statement. And also a couple of statements on which statement you are substituting where would add more clarity.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini I have now made my final version